# how C++20 module export dependency in third-party

Tags: c++, logging, module, export, c++20

I plan to use the c++20 module to encapsulate a log library based on the spdlog library.

But in the log interface, I used `spdlog::format_string_t<Args...>`  as the interface. If I don't #include <spdlog> in test.cpp, it will not compile.

I think it may be necessary to export `spdlog::format_string_t<Args...>` related classes together, but I don't know how to do it, can anyone provide some advice, thank you!

```
//test.cpp

// #include <spdlog/sinks/stdout_color_sinks.h> // only work when I #include this file
import core.log;

using namespace rain;

int main()
{
    LogWarn("ssss{0}", 1);
    LogWarn("ssss");
    LogWarn(111);

    return 0;
}

//log.ixx
//
......
template<NotFormatString... Args>
struct LogWarn : public Log<spdlog::level::warn, Args...>
{
    LogWarn(
        spdlog::format_string_t<Args...> message,
        Args&&... args,
        std::source_location source_location = std::source_location::current()) :
        Log<spdlog::level::warn, Args...>(message, std::forward<Args>(args)..., source_location)
    {}
};

template<>
struct LogWarn<> : public Log<spdlog::level::warn>
{
    template<typename T>
    LogWarn(T msg, std::source_location source_location = std::source_location::current()) :
        Log<spdlog::level::warn>(msg, source_location)
    {}
};

template<NotFormatString... Args>
LogWarn(spdlog::format_string_t<Args...>, Args&&...) -> LogWarn<Args...>;

template<NotFormatString T>
LogWarn(T) -> LogWarn<>;
......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your "encapsulation" of a library is leaky (aka: users of your "encapsulation" will need to directly use things defined in the library), then... users will need to *directly use* things defined in that library. A library that is defined by headers, not by modules.

So if you've made a leaky encapsulation, the user will have to both `import` your module and `#include` the library it leaks. That's what "leaky" means.

If there's a library that already exists and uses regular headers, you cannot *externally* force the stuff in that library to be exposed through a proper module. The best a user can do is `import` headers as header units.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to hide third-party's leaky.